# Can I get a tax break while renovating a house that is being auctioned?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, new-york, home-renovation

Looking at a Homepath home that needs a major rehab, the house is a cash only deal, and all fixed up might be worth a decent amount of money ( 200 k or so ) but it's being sold for 60k in the current condition. But the taxes are quite high ( so I'm assuming that the value on the books is also quite high ). Is there any way that I can lower the taxes on the property either while I'm working on it, or just argue that since it's being sold for 60k , it should not be taxed at such a high rate?

The property has in in Ulster Count NY
It is assessed at 213k and being sold for 60k 
Taxes are $8,207 so I guess the tax rate can be extrapolated from that 
4% or so?

Comment: This question needs far more information to be answerable - in particular, what is the jurisdiction [country, state, county, etc.], what are the total taxes, what is the tax rate, and what is the assessed value to which that rate is applied?

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine for the taxing jurisdiction when the next tax appraisal will be done. In some cases the appraisal is done every year, or two, or three. In other cases it is also done when the property is sold. The county tax office website should contain this information. They will also have information on how to appeal.

Most jurisdictions do have a way of looking up not only the rates but the value of the property in question. You will also be interested in determining if the tax value of the property is lower due to local/state laws that limit the growth in value from one assessment to another. A sale of the property could trigger a catchup for the value.

It is possible that the degraded value of the home has already been factored into the assessment. It is also possible that it hasn't. Keep in mind that taxes in some jurisdictions can be more complicated because there is also a town/city/county component, and some places that also breakout other items on the tax bill like storm water management, schools, pest spraying. These other items can be based on value, square footage of the lot, or a flat amount.

You should get a local opinion on the likelihood of a successful appeal, and how much adjustment you would be able to get. Depending on the sale date and the due date for the taxes, you may be forced to pay the higher tax rate for a while until either the next re-appraisal or the next appeal window.

Note: the fact that it is being auctioned may mean that what you pay for the house may be immaterial because the tax authorities could determine that the motivation to sell quickly could have depressed the value. This type of sale will not impact the value of other houses and can't be used as a basis for determining the value of other properties.